# FTP Sync large number of files

Tags: batch-file, ftp, synchronization

So I am using an old pc of mine to generate a visual map of a game map. In total I have approx. 2.4 million files and folders and it's about 160GB of disk space. Once the main job is synced only a thousand or so files change every day.

What I am trying to do is to sync the entire contents to a webhost via ftp and keep it updated as the files change on my local PC.

So what needs to happen is something that either listens to file changes or scans for changes on a constant loop(aka batch file) and uploads files as soon as changes were detected.

I tried using GoodSync for this but it takes 17 hrs to analyse and by that time a number of files have changed. (yes I can split it easily into 8 jobs)

Is there any software or string of batch files that would do this for me and utilize multiple connections for a ftp username?

Comment: Scanning for changes among such a large set of files is infeasible.  Your software that changes the files should write a log of changes, which you can later utilize for syncing.

Comment: I have to say that I agree with you. But unfortunately there is no file change logging capabilities in "mapcrafter" that I can find. Only logs amount of changes and progress messages on the highest logging value.

Comment: I guess, your best option is to get mapcrafter sources from github and tweak its writing functionality accordingly.

Comment: WatchDirectory has the capability.  It has two settings where the Windows File System will notify the software of changes in the directory structure. You can use Default or FAST monitoring.  In your case it sounds like you would want to use FAST.  Then when you use the FTP plugin, you can tell it to create the same directory structure on the FTP server as what is on your computer.

Answer (score 0):

If you computer runs linux, you can use this simple shell command.

```
while inotifywait -r -e modify,create,delete,move {local_dir}; do
  lftp -u {ftp_user},{ftp_password} {ftp_server} -e "mirror -R {local_dir} {remote_dir}; quit" >/dev/null 2>&1
done &
```

Instead {...} you should put your specific data. For example:

{local_dir} replace with /home/me/documents/my_data
{ftp_server} replace with ftp.myserver.com
{remote_dir} replace with /public_html/my_folder

inotifywait and lftp can be simply installed by:

```
sudo apt install inotifywait, lftp
```

Command works in background. It watches local folder for: modify, create, delete, move. When event detected, it executes ftp syncing from local folder to remote folder on ftp server.

If you delete files in local folder, its copy on remote folder will not be deleted. If you want folders to be fully synced, with the file deletion on remote folder (when missing in local folder), modify command:

```
... mirror -R --delete {local_dir} ...
```